# Why does tar fail to create an archive when called via Python's subprocess.call while using a * wildcard?

Tags: python, subprocess, tar

I'm writing a python script that should extract some data from within the existing files and then pack the original files into several tarballs. The filename format looks like this:

`system_yymmddT0000.zip`

where `system` can be one of several names and`YYMMDDThhmm` is a date and time of creation.

To make this work, I'm using tar through Python's `subprocess.call` so, for files starting with date 1704 like `SAP_1704T0000.zip`, the command is:

`subprocess.call(["tar", "-cvf", "SAP_2017_04.tar", "SAP_1704*", "1>", "SAP_2017_04.filelist"])`

However, when I run this script, I get the following error:

```
tar: SAP_1704*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: 1>: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: SAP_2017_04.filelist: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I also tried to pack all the arguments together like this:

`subprocess.call(["tar", "-cvf SAP_2017_04.tar SAP_1704* 1> SAP_2017_04.filelist"])` (no commas between arguments). However, then I got the following error:

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, since manually navigating inside the folder and running the command `tar cvf SAP_2017_04.tar SAP_1704* 1> SAP_2017_04.filelist`
 works just fine.

Comment: Try running with optional parameter `shell = True`

Comment: @CMMCD I'm sorry, I'm not sure if you mean to run the Python script itself with optional parameter, or just the subprocess. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)`

Comment: Okay, I tried both `subprocess.call(["tar", "-cvf SAP_2017_04.tar SAP_1704* 1> SAP_2017_04.filelist"], shell=True)` and `subprocess.call(["tar", "-cvf", "SAP_2017_04.tar", "SAP_1704*", "1>", "SAP_2017_04.filelist"], shell=True)`, but now I get a different error.

Comment: Specifically this error: `tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux' or '--test-label'  options
Try tar --help' or tar --usage' for more information.`

Comment: Did you try same command once on cmd prompt or terminal?

Comment: @ErHarshRathore I tried to run in the terminal the exact same command that the Python script should be running through `subprocess.call`. As I wrote in the main post, it works, but when I run it through Python, it gives an error, see above.

Comment: try this `subprocess.call(["tar", "-cvf","SAP_2017_04.tar SAP_1704* 1>  SAP_2017_04.filelist"])` and paste the result

Comment: @ErHarshRathore Same result. `tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux' or '--test-label'  options
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
`

Comment: @ErHarshRathore Actually, I tried `subprocess.call(["tar", "-cvf","SAP_2017_04.tar SAP_1704* 1> SAP_2017_04.filelist"], shell=True)`, which threw `-Acdtrux` error. I've tried to run the command exactly like you wrote it, and now it throws `tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive`

Comment: @Ludolph314, when you use an array with `shell=True`, only the first item is treated by the shell as code; the other items are arguments *to the shell*, which your code in the first entry has to actually read if they're going to do anything other than be silently ignored.

Comment: @Ludolph314, ...it's an exact equivalent to what you'd get if you ran `sh -c 'tar' '-cvf' 'SAP_2017_04.tar SAP_1704* 1> SAP_2017_04.filelist'`, which will give you the exact same "refusing to create an empty archive" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards aren't processed by `tar`, they need to be processed by the program that calls it. *Usually*, that program is a shell.

However, it doesn't have to be; you can get much safer operation (if any of your parameters are user-configurable) by doing the work in native Python instead of using `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.call(['tar', '-cvf', 'SAP_2017_04.tar'] + glob.glob('SAP_1704*'),
                stdout=open('SAP_2017_04.filelist', 'w'))
```

- Instead of `1>somefile` (an instruction *to your shell* to redirect stdout, FD 1, to write to `somefile`), we use `stdout=open('somefile', 'w')` to tell Python the same thing.
- Instead of just putting `SAP_1704*` directly in the command line, we call `glob.glob('SAP_1704*')` in Python, and add the list it returns to the argument list.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, figured it out myself (at least I think so). It works like this:

```
substring = r"tar, -cvf SAP_2017_04.tar SAP_1704* 1> SAP_2017_04.filelist"
subprocess.call(substring, shell=True)
```

It seems there were two problems - escaping some special characters and also attempting to pass a list of arguments to the `subprocess.call` while it should be passed as a single string when using `shell=True`.

Big thanks to @CMMCD @BoarGules and @ErHarshRathore for putting me on the right track!

Comment: You *can* successfully use a list with `shell=True`. Doing it meaningfully might look like this: `subprocess.call(['tar -czf "$1.tar" "$1"* >"$1.filelist"', '_', 'SAP_2017_04'], shell=True)` -- see how the first argument is the code that gets run, the second argument (a `_`) becomes `$0`; the third argument becomes the value for `$1` which the code uses.

Comment: ...the value to doing that is that even if an attacker controls the variable that's substituted for `'SAP_2017_04'`, they can't run arbitrary code of their choice -- if they put, say, `'$(rm -rf ~)'` in that variable, it'll create a file named `$(rm -rf ~).tar`, instead of deleting your home directory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy A possibility of an attack via harmful code inside the variable that is used in place of `SAP_2017_04` shouldn't probably be a problem in this case, because the value assigned to this variable is *always* found by using `glob.glob` looking specifically for filenames that start with the given format `system_timestamp.zip`. Also, the whole script only takes a source directory as an input parameter. However you are right, your solution is definitely safer and more elegant.